# Scala: can a generic class implement its parameter?

Tags: class, scala, generics, dynamic, proxy

I am quite new to Scala.
I am trying to define a generic class `Proxy[T]` that should be usable 
in any place where instances of T are expected.
So I was thinking about something like

```
class Proxy[T] extends Dynamic with T
```

but this does not compiles in Scala (I get "class type required but T found").
So the answer to my question seem to be "No", but still it looks weird to me.

Is it possible in Scala to circumvent this problem or am I missing an important conceptual bit?

The most similar thing I've found to what I need is scala.ref.Reference[T] which however extends (()=>T)
and cannot be used in places where T is expected (at least this is my understanding).
I suppose that https://code.google.com/p/classgenerator/ can solve my problem but it seems a bit overkilling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to achieve what you described.

What you may use instead is run-time proxies (see java.lang.reflect.Proxy). Another alternative is CGLIB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you can do:

```
class MyProxy[T](val self:T)
object MyProxy {
  implicit def unwrap[T](p:MyProxy[T]):T = p.self
}
```

Now you can use `MyProxy[T]` everywhere where a `T` is required. The compiler will find the `implicit` "unwrap" function and call it. `MyProxy` *is* not a `T`, but it *can be converted* to `T`.